# Is there a way to filter non zero data from an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, sql

is there a way to filter and group data from an ObservableCollection that has values greater than zero?

I have an excel file that load into an ObservableCollection but within the file could be some values with zero, and with this criteria, I need to run a query into SQL to get some data, but with these zero codes when I run the query doesn't return anything.

Example

[image]

I need to build a query for each of this combinations but there are more than 90k records in my ObservableCollection I'm looking for a clever solution to group all the records with the same pattern (In this case row 3 and 4 for example) does not need to have the same values only the same pattern in order to run one single large query with all of these codes.

Currently, I'm doing it in this way:

```
foreach (var item in _sourceStructure)
        {
            query = prepareQuery(item);
            RunQuery(query);
            if (errorMessage.Length > 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(errorMessage);
            }
            query = "";
        }
```

And in my preparQuery method, I have something like this

```
query = @"SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 FROM SomeTable WHERE "

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Column1.ToString()) && item.Column1.ToString() != "0")
                {
                    query = query + "Column1= " + "'" + item.Column1.ToString() + "'" + " and ";
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Column2.ToString()) && item.Column2.ToString() != "0")
                {
                    query = query + "Column2= " + "'" + item.Column2.ToString() + "'" + " and ";
                }
```

This works "fine" but takes a lot of time to complete.
If you find a better solution I can try it, I'm just looking for some advice.

Comment: To speed up query you need to do two things 1)  You need an interface that returns an array for each row 2) Then use the linq Any to get rows with zeroes like : var results = _sourceStructure.Where(x => x.Any(y => y == "0")).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng the interface will be called every time that the query runs (for each record), that would be faster? I'm not quite familiar with interfaces, I know how to implement it but not how much increase the speed. Could you please give me an example of how to implement it?

Comment: It would be faster doing it in linq than the way you are currently doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop calling ToString so many times. You should do it once and store the value. And consider using string.Format or StringBuilder. Adding is very resource intensive.